# does offsetof work with typeof if type is new?

Tags: c, typeof, offsetof, c23

I read on cppreference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof):

> Even though it is specified in C23 that defining a new type in
> offsetof is undefined behavior, such usage is only partially supported
> by implementations even in earlier modes: `offsetof(struct Foo { int a; }, a)` is usually supported, but `offsetof(struct Foo { int a, b; }, a)`
> is not because of the comma in the definition of struct Foo.

So it won't work with new types because of the commas in the definitions, does that mean using `typeof` will make it work (since it'll wrap the type in parentheses)?

```
offsetof(typeof(struct Foo { int a,b; }), a);
```

edit:

if this doesn't work, is there a workaround to have the struct be defined inside the `offsetof`?

for example:

```
void *dummy;
offsetof(typeof(*((struct { int a; int b; }*)dummy)), a);
```

Comment: Why you declare the structure in `typeof` body and not before it and use structure name or typedef?

Comment: Notably you are still able to use the old school offsetof hack with `typeof`: `#define offsetof_ex(type, memb) ( &( ((typeof(type)*)0)->(memb) ) )`  which can be called as `offsetof_ex(struct Foo { int a; int b; }, b)` and gives the result i.e `4`.

Comment: @Lundin this works if I remove the parentheses around `memb`. But is this allowed? aren't you referencing a NULL pointer here?

Comment: This is an old trick - it doesn't dereference anything, we are just dealing with addresses. But yeah it is fishy since a null pointer could boil down to some special thing on some system, like an instruction trap. Not undefined but definitely non-portable behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C 2023 draft N3096 7.21 4 says, of `offsetof(type, member-designator)`:

> … If the specified *type* defines a new type or if the specified member is a bit-field, the behavior is undefined.

Therefore the C standard does not require `offsetof` to work with a new type in a conforming C implementation, regardless of whether or not the macro argument for `type` contains a comma. If the argument contains a `typeof` in which a new type is defined, the argument defines a new type and is subject to the above.

Another reason it might not work with a new type, hypothetically, is the macro might use the type argument in its replacement list in a way that causes problems due to multiple definitions of the type. It is not a correct logical inference that because X (presence of a comma) causes Y (`offsetof` will not work) that Not X will cause Not Y.

Comment: I see. But what if I don't name it? ```offsetof(typeof(struct { int a,b; }), a)```

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi `If the specified type defines a new type ... the behavior is undefined.` Wrapping declaration into `typeof` does not change anything. It's still UB. Maybe the requirement will be loosen in C2Y.